# Injection of unknown provider in Angularjs Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am getting this error while running my angular app. I have installed all packages using npm. Is this issue direct me some version conflict between angular and angular-animate?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider <- $$isDocumentHidden <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24isDocumentHidden…eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4381
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4529)
    at angular.js:4386
    at getService (angular.js:4529)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4561)
    at angular.js:4387
    at getService (angular.js:4529)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4561)
    at angular.js:4387
```

Can someone explain what to do?

Comment: Have you loaded the module that contains that provider?
Example: `app.module('yourModule', ['moduleWithProvider'])`

Comment: yeah I loaded that module.

Comment: Have you include all the dependency js files in index.html?

Comment: Check for the versions 
If you have an angular with lower version than the version of angular-animate then lower down the version of angular-animate and check out if it works fine

Comment: yes I did it @CharanCherry
Can you give a link that I can downgrade version of angular-animate?

Comment: if u have done bower install then go to bower.json file there u could see "angular-animate": "some version", specify there 1.4 or 1.5 id you are using angular 1.5 version

Comment: Here it is:
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.6",
    "angular-animate":"1.4.6",
}

Comment: yes ,
does it works?

Comment: no man . I tried `npm install`. I have been suggested something like this:
`myproject suggests angular 1.4.6
angula-animate suggests angular 1.6.*`

Comment: yor are using 1.4.14 . https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/api/ngAnimate

Comment: no @Manikandan it's 1.4.6

Comment: i solved it. @Shikhathakur you should put your comment into answer. That worked. I just downgraded my angular-animate.

Comment: ABOVE screen says http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?

Comment: yeah But I downgraded them later. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to downgrade your angular-animate version to the version of Angular.

If you have used `bower install` then go to the `bower.json` file. There you can see `"angular-animate": "some version"`, replace the value with 1.4 (or 1.5 if you are using Angular 1.5).

Comment: I have edited your post. Please check [answer] and the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), your answer was very poor to read. Just because you pasted it from your comment doesn't mean it should be unreadable. You not only write answers for OP, but also for future users.

Comment: @Kyll
sure, Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to confirm the Shikha's answer.
I had the same issue. My angular version was 1.5.x and my angular-animate version was 1.6.x 
As a result, I got following error:

`eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue.`

so, I had to downgrade my angular-animate to version 1.4.x with following command:

`npm install angular-animate@1.4.8`

then, it worked very well.